# "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop" when adding new element to the list

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb, list, ids

I am developing a list of items using React, Express (axios) and MongoDB.

Items of an array of the list are retrieved from MongoDB, displayed in a component and the user can add new items (and save them in MongoDB).

The problem is that `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop"` is shown because new element are added to the list using `id: Math.random()` attribute (although those ids are not submitted to the DB)

App.tsx (**HERE the list of items is fetched with ids generated by MongoDB**)

```
export default function App() {
    const [ExpenseAndAmountList, setExpenseAndAmountList] = useState<
      Array<{
        id: number,
        expenseTitle: string,
        expenseAmount: string,
      }>
    >([]);


 useEffect(() => {
    const expensesListResp = async () => {
      await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist')
      .then(
        response => setExpenseAndAmountList(response.data && response.data.length > 0 ? response.data : []));
    }
    expensesListResp();
  }, []);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ExpenseAmountInputContainer 
          expenseAndAmountList={ExpenseAndAmountList}
          setExpenseAndAmountList={setExpenseAndAmountList}
          setTotalExpensesAmount={setTotalExpensesAmount}
          totalExpenses={TotalExpensesAmount}
        />

        <DynamicList 
          expenseAndAmountList={ExpenseAndAmountList} 
          currencySymbol={Currency}
          setExpenseAndAmountList={setExpenseAndAmountList}
        />
      </div>
    );
}
```

ExpenseAmountInputContainer.tsx (**HERE items are posted to MongoDB list without any id**)

```
interface Props {
    expenseAndAmountList: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void; 
}

const ExpenseAmountInputContainer: React.FC<Props> = (
        {
            expenseAndAmountList, 
            setExpenseAndAmountList,
        }: Props
    ) => {
    
    const [Expense, setExpense] = useState<string>('');
    const [Amount, setAmount] = useState<string>('');

    const AddItemToList = () => {
        if (Expense !== '' && Amount !== '' && Number(Amount) > 0) {

            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist', 
            {
                expenseTitle: Expense,
                expenseAmount: Amount
            });
            
            setExpense("");
            setAmount("");

            const expensesListResp = async () => {
                await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist')
                .then(
                response => setExpenseAndAmountList(response.data && response.data.length > 0 ? response.data : []));
            }
            expensesListResp();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <InputItem 
                onChange={setExpense} 
                onBlur={setExpense} 
                title="Expense" 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Item title" 
                value={Expense}
            />
            <InputItem 
                onChange={setAmount}  
                onBlur={setAmount}  
                title="Amount" 
                type="number" 
                placeholder="Expense cost" 
                value={Amount}
            />
            <AddButton 
                onClick={AddItemToList} 
                content="Add expense"

            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default ExpenseAmountInputContainer;
```

ExpenseAndAmountObject.tsx (interface used at ExpenseAmountInputContainer.tsx)

```
export interface ExpenseAndAmountObject {
    id: number,
    expenseTitle: string,
    expenseAmount: string,
}
```

DynamicList.tsx

```
import { ExpenseAndAmountObject } from '../ExpenseAndAmountObject';
  interface ListItemsArray {
    expenseAndAmountList: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    currencySymbol: string;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void;
  }

  const DynamicList: React.FC<ListItemsArray> = (
    {
      expenseAndAmountList, 
      currencySymbol,
      setExpenseAndAmountList
    }: ListItemsArray) => {

    return (
        <>
            <List>
                {expenseAndAmountList.map(item => (
                  <ExpensesListItem
                    expenseTitle={item.expenseTitle} 
                    expenseAmount={item.expenseAmount}
                    currencySymbol={currencySymbol}
                    item={item}
                    items={expenseAndAmountList}
                    setExpenseAndAmountList={setExpenseAndAmountList}
                  />
                ))} 
            </List>
        </>
      );
  }
  
export default DynamicList;
```

How could the problem be solved?

Comment: Where are you setting the item id properties? Are you setting them in the backend? `Math.random` really isn't a good use case for generating unique ids.

Comment: My comment was misleading, I was not using `Math.random`. AT ExpenseAmountInputContainer.tsx items are posted to MongoDB without any ids (as they are generated in MongoDB)

Comment: Be that as it may, it's still unclear where you are adding any `id` properties when adding new elements to a list. Where are `id`s being generated? Where is the error being thrown? It seems you are generating them in your backend. If they aren't unique then you'll have this frontend issue. Can we see the relevant backend code?

Comment: In DynamicList.tsx, are you setting the key prop for components created using `map()`?

Comment: I've not been setting key prop at any place and I've just added an attribute `key={item.id}` to the `<List>`. I'm trying to achieve that item.id would be `_id` generated by MongoDB (maybe it is not a correct approach..?)

Comment: I've checked that in the component DynamicList the array of items from MongoDB is accessible, i.e. equals to `[{_id: "60c970297ba73b083ec13dbc", expenseTitle: “first_title, expenseAmount: "1", __v: 0},{_id: "60c9782dae534110361f359a", expenseTitle: “second”title, expenseAmount: “2”, __v: 0}]`. However, when I check the values of props of items in ExpensesListItem, the value of `key={item.id}  equals to undefined`

Comment: Well, you still haven't explained where you are adding new items and/or ids, but you *are* missing React keys on the mapped `expenseAndAmountList` array in `DynamicList`. You need to add a React key to the `ExpensesListItem` component you are mapping to. See [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. I'm adding new items to <DynamicList> component. <DynamicList> contains a component <List> which represents the array ob objects, each of newly generated <List> component is an object of an array (example of such object `{_id: "60c970297ba73b083ec13dbc", expenseTitle: “first_title, expenseAmount: "1", __v: 0}`).

Comment: I've just added an attribute key={item.id} to the <List> hoping that it would be the `_id` of an object but apparently the values of `item.id` = undefined

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the prop `key` when you render lists.

```
import { ExpenseAndAmountObject } from '../ExpenseAndAmountObject';
  interface ListItemsArray {
    expenseAndAmountList: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    currencySymbol: string;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void;
  }

  const DynamicList: React.FC<ListItemsArray> = (
    {
      expenseAndAmountList, 
      currencySymbol,
      setExpenseAndAmountList
    }: ListItemsArray) => {

    return (
        <>
            <List>
                {expenseAndAmountList.map(item => (
                  <ExpensesListItem

                    key={} // <-----  SOME UNIQUE ID HERE!!!!!!!!

                    expenseTitle={item.expenseTitle} 
                    expenseAmount={item.expenseAmount}
                    currencySymbol={currencySymbol}
                    item={item}
                    items={expenseAndAmountList}
                    setExpenseAndAmountList={setExpenseAndAmountList}
                  />
                ))} 
            </List>
        </>
      );
  }
  
export default DynamicList;
```

Please see the documentation that explains this behavior https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: I've added an attribute `key={item.id}` to the `<List>` as per your example. item.id is supposed to be `_id` generated by MongoDB (I've checked that in the component DynamicList the array of items from MongoDB is accessible, i.e. equals to `[{_id: "60c970297ba73b083ec13dbc", expenseTitle: “first_title, expenseAmount: "1", __v: 0},{_id: "60c9782dae534110361f359a", expenseTitle: “second”title, expenseAmount: “2”, __v: 0}]`). However, when I check the values of props of items in ExpensesListItem, the value of `key={item.id}  equals to undefined`. Maybe you know why? Thanks in advance!